# Parse (Coud Code) with Internet Explorer 9... over HTTPS

Tags: internet-explorer-9, parse-platform, xdomainrequest

I'm trying to log onto a parseapp.com-hosted site with an IE9 browser.  I'm getting this error:

"IE's XDomainRequest does not supply error info"

I'm accessing the webpage via SSL (https://myapp.parseapp.com)..

Using latest (1.2.18) version of Parse.js..

*snippet from Parse.js:*

```
  Parse._ajaxIE8 = function(method, url, data) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
    xdr.onload = function() {
      var response;
      try {
        response = JSON.parse(xdr.responseText);
      } catch (e) {
        promise.reject(e);
      }
      if (response) {
        promise.resolve(response);
      }
    };
    xdr.onerror = xdr.ontimeout = function() {
      // Let's fake a real error message.
      var fakeResponse = {
        responseText: JSON.stringify({
          code: Parse.Error.X_DOMAIN_REQUEST,
          error: "IE's XDomainRequest does not supply error info."
        })
      };
      promise.reject(fakeResponse);
    };
    xdr.onprogress = function() {};
    xdr.open(method, url);
    xdr.send(data);
    return promise;
  };
```

Comment: What is the question?